# How to mimick VB use of COM Object Interface using C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, interface, com

I am working with a vendor's API.   It is supplied as various COM object DLL's.    I am trying to gain access to method "CreateDisconnectedADORecordset" contained within the interface IBBUtilityCode.

A code sample from the vendor is as follows:

```
Dim oReservices As New REServices
Dim oUtilCode As IBBUtilityCode
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM CONSTITUENT_BANK"

oReservices.Init SessionContext
Set oUtilCode = oReservices

Set rs = oUtilCode.CreateDisconnectedADORecordset(sSQL)
```

They seem to be using the interface "IBBUtilityCode" by first declaring a pointer to one, then casting "oReservices" as a pointer to the interface???

I am not a VB programmer, so I really haven't a clue.

How can this be done with C#?    Any help and/or pointers you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They seem to be using the interface "IBBUtilityCode" by first declaring a pointer to one, then casting "oReservices" as a pointer to the interface???

The concept of a class implementing an interface is not special to COM or Visual Basic, you should be familiar with it in C# as well.  Just as in this VB6 code, you don't need a cast to obtain the interface reference.  The translation is entirely mechanical:

```
var oReservices = new REServices();
oReservices.Init(SessionContext);
IBBUtilityCode oUtilCode = oReservices
var sSQL = "SELECT * FROM CONSTITUENT_BANK"
var rs = oUtilCode.CreateDisconnectedADORecordset(sSQL)
```

No lack of traps with this kind of component, ADO has *not* aged well.  A minor install or configuration problem can turn into a pretty unsolvable headache.  Be sure to contact the vendor or author of this component when you have trouble.

Comment: Hans: Your solution is correct and I had tried something like that earlier.  What I discovered that prevented me from using it was that I needed to set "Embed Interop Types" in the properties of the DLL to "false".   Once I made that change, everything began to work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using cominvoke. Here is a link from Microsoft explaining it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx

Here is an example of it from that page:

```
// Create an instance of a COM coclass:
FilgraphManager graphManager = new FilgraphManager();

// See if it supports the IMediaControl COM interface. 
// Note that this will throw a System.InvalidCastException if 
// the cast fails. This is equivalent to QueryInterface for 
// COM objects:
IMediaControl mc = (IMediaControl) graphManager;

// Now you call a method on a COM interface: 
mc.Run();
```